# Does adobe analytics decrease website performance?

Tags: analytics

We currently use Adobe analytics for online forms to measure completion rates and field drop-offs. I recently discovered a form that had not been tagged and put in a request for it to be tagged. The feedback I've received is that tagging a web page adds strain to the web page and increases load time as well as having an additional cost to storage space of the data. Is this true? My confusion arises from the fact that we use Adobe analytics for other forms.

Answer (score 1):

> Does adobe analytics decrease website performance?

Yes. Adding anything adds to page load time. Images, extra CSS, everything.

Analytics typically use JavaScript, so in addition to the extra load time for the JS file, there are further delays while the script executes. That means adding it will be more noticeable than adding a static resource such as an appropriately scaled image, for example.

Use the network profiling tools built in to your browser to evaluate load time, or try a third-party testing service such as [GTmetrix](https://gtmetrix.com/), [Sucuri](https://performance.sucuri.net/), or [keycdn](https://tools.keycdn.com/performance). These will tell you exactly how much slower your pages are with the extra analytics bloat.

Don't forget that with the rapidly increasing adoption of browser ad blockers, your analytics scripts will be blocked by more and more users. Using analytics scripts will still add some value, but comparing results against more reliable figures such as server logs will become necessary to see how many visitors are present.

Answer (score 0):

First, using appropriate meta tags on your pages will help with search results and SEO. I prefer to add meta tags, description, etc to my pages to improve being found and rankings.

Now, about tagging in general.  The increase in load time depends a lot on whether you are measuring actual load time or perceived load time. Perceived load time, the time between request and when the user can "use" the page, is what impacts your click throughs, abandonment and user perception of your site.  And yes, every tag you add will have an impact as the page waits for the tag resource to respond.

With that being said, if you have tagged your other forms and keep the tags to a minimum, you should not see any big difference since we are talking about 1 page.  If you were tagging all of your forms, yes that would be a big impact.

As a suggestion, perhaps you can review your forms and your tags and make sure that you've assigned only the necessary tag(s) and keep the number as small as possible. That way you have the benefits of tagging while keeping the impact as small as possible.